# jQuery opening screen

Tags: jquery, screen

Good Day!

I made a jQuery opening screen. It has three parts 1) left screen 2) right screen 3) open button.
when visitors will visit  the homepage then see opening screen with a button (Just Click and Enjoy!). When visitor will click the existing button, then left screen will move to left and right screen will move to right  (both part animate slowly), also Existing button will hide. That means visitor will see the main page of the website. Everything is OK till this.

My problem- when visitor come back to home page from another page or reload the homepage the opening screen comes again. But I want to show the opening screen only one time. Also it can be work for a specific duration (ex: opening screen will come 1 time within 1hour)

Thanks to All.

Comment: use cookie,localstorage to store the state of the screen

Comment: Store a flag to the cookie / localstorage for the animation done. Similarly add datetime variable value to store current time and calculate one hour and disable the flag if it exceeds the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to store the status of your animation. Check this status on each load and show/hide your animation accordingly.

Here is the link for one of the jQuery plugin for cookie handling
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie